# how to generate shapfiles into a spcific folder

Tags: python, geopandas

i am using geopandas package, and in the below code i want to modify the following line:

```
LIDARGDF.to_file(filename='LIDAR-Data.shp', driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

so that the generated .shp files are to be placed inside a particular folder called `out` for example.
to achieve that i did the following:

```
LIDARGDF.to_file(filename='/out/LIDAR-Data.shp', driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

however python generated an error and does not allow creating the folder `out`
please let me know how to modify the below posted code so it generates the .shp files into a specific folder

**code**

```
featuresAsPolygonCoordinates3DInEPSG25832 = getFeaturesAsPolygonCoordinatesInEPSG25831(featuresAsPolygonCoordinates3DInEPSG4326)
LIDARAsPolygonGeometry = bindPolygonCoordinates(getPolygonsLongitudeValuesArray(), getPolygonsLatitudeValuesArray())
LIDARGDF = buildGeoDataFrameForGeometry(LIDARAsPolygonGeometry)
LIDARGDF.to_file(filename='LIDAR-Data.shp', driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- create the folder manually
- creating it before exporting the shapefile:

```
import os
try:
    os.mkdir('./out')
except FileExistsError:
    print('folder already exists!')

LIDARGDF.to_file(filename='out/LIDAR-Data.shp', driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Comment: hey  , may be you can answerthis as well:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67431202/how-to-refer-to-folders-name-from-configuration-file