# how to refer to folder's name from configuration file

Tags: python

in the below posted code i want to refer to the folder's name from the configuration file. the name of the folder is saved in the configurarions and i want to refer to it.
the below code when i run it it generates an error.

is it possible to refer to the folder name from the configuration file. if yes, please let me know how.

**config**

```
[Grid]
cell_width=10
cell_height=10
geopandas_output_folder=GeopandasOutput
```

**code**:

```
 try:
        os.mkdir('.'/config['Grid']['geopandas_output_folder'])
    except FileExistsError:
        print('folder already exists!')
```

**update**:

```
    try:
        os.mkdir('./' + config['Grid']['geopandas_output_folder'])
    except FileExistsError:
        print('folder already exists!')
    boundingGeometryAsGDF.to_file(filename='./' + config['Grid']['geopandas_output_folder'] + '/' + 'boundingGeometry2.shp', driver="ESRI Shapefile")
    gdpolygonAsGDFf.to_file(filename='./' + config['Grid']['geopandas_output_folder'] + '/' + 'gdf__%d.shp'%(cnt), driver="ESRI Shapefile")

error received:
File "fiona/ogrext.pyx", line 1054, in fiona.ogrext.WritingSession.start
fiona.errors.DriverIOError: Failed to create file GeopandasOutput\boundingGeometry2.shp: No such file or directory
```

Comment: you can read the config file and then split the line to get the folder name

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is due to incorrect string construction:

```
# this gives an error
out_path = '.'/config['Grid']['geopandas_output_folder']

# this doesn't
out_path = './'+config['Grid']['geopandas_output_folder']

# then you do:
try:
    os.mkdir(out_path)
except FileExistsError:
    print('folder already exists!')
```

Comment: i tried it but it does not worl.please have a look at the update section added above